# Is there a way to link from meta to a tag on the main site?

Tags: support, tags, markdown, meta

Sometimes I'm writing on meta and would like to use the method `[tag:` + *tagname* + `]` to link to a tag on the main site but that construct links to a tag on the meta site.

Is there a way to do what I want and link from the meta site to the main site for a particular tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `[tag:]` always links to main site tags.

[keigo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keigo) - http://**japanese**.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keigo

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) - http://**meta**.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion

```
[tag:keigo]
[meta-tag:discussion]
```

Comment: That's funny I was sure I accepted this answer as soon as I saw it.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, on the first few days after the markup `[tag:…]` was introduced, it indeed linked to meta when used on meta.  As YOU wrote, now this markup links to the main site even when used on meta.  From [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange):

> - 2010-11-07: Behavior of `[tag:tags]` on meta sites updated to refer to the parent site by default; new syntax introduced for a meta-site's own tags ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69513/allow-specifying-sites-for-the-new-tag-formatting-at-least-to-some-degree/69644#69644)).
> - 2010-11-05: Posting tags inside questions and answers [now works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482). Example: instead of writing `` [`[tags]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) `` to display [`[tags]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags), users can now write `[tag:tags]` to display [tags](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags).

Comment: Aha so I'm not going crazy after all (-: